# How to merge pixels WITHIN an image based on their rgb values in python?

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-learn, python-imaging-library

So far , I've divided an image into blocks of specific size and these blocks have the mean color of the original block. Now, I have to merge these blocks based on their similarity,  where each block contains a single pixel value(mean color value). For this , I have been trying to merge pixels within an image based on their rgb values. So far I've not found anything that would help me with this. So kindly help me to solve this problem. What I've done so far...

x and y are the block sizes. Here x=y=16.

Input :[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJWT8.png)
Output: [Processed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUzoc.png)
I've not implemented anything after this since I don't know how to proceed further. Now I've to group the pixels in the processed image based on their similarity.

```
i=0
j=0
m=16
n=16

l=[]   
data = np.zeros( (256,256,3), dtype=np.uint8 )
while(m<=256):
    while(n<=256):
        l=image[i:m,j:n]

        print(l)
        r=0
        g=0
        b=0
        for q in range(len(l)):
            for w in range(len(l)):
                r=r+l[q][w][0]
                g=g+l[q][w][1]
                b=b+l[q][w][2]

        r=r/(x*y)
        b=b/(x*y)
        g=g/(x*y)
        k=[r,g,b]
        data[i:m,j:n]=k
        j=j+16
        n=n+16

    i=i+16
    m=m+16
    j=0
    n=16
img = smp.toimage( data )
data1 = np.asarray( img, dtype="int32" )


cv2.imwrite(os.path.join('G:/AI package/datasets/_normalized',filename),data1)
```

Comment: Please attach sample input with expected output and also some code would be helpful with the exact problems you are facing while implementing this.

Comment: This sounds like mean shift segmentation base on RGB. BTW, python is quite slow on the loops, having 4 nested loops is not the best idea. It is better if you can vectorize some of the things done.

Comment: @ZdaR I have attached my code now. But I've not implemented anything after this since I don't know how to proceed. I just need to group my pixels now based on their similarity.

Comment: Not sure whether I understand the "merging" right. If you just want to combine each 16x16 pixels, you could resize the image with size factor 1/16 with linear filtering interpolation and then manually resize to duplicate each pixel 16x16 times without any fancy interpolation.

Comment: can you please explain this: *Now I've to group the pixels in the processed image based on their similarity*. What output are you expecting after this operation?

Comment: @ZdaR  consider an image divided into blocks of size 16x16 with each block having a single pixel color. I need to merge NEARBY pixels having least color variations between them(for eg.. variations of blue color can be grouped together). Did I clarify your question?

Comment: So let's imagine you have 4 values arranged in a 2x2 fashion, now if the elements of first row are similar, then what would be expected output? That similar value copied to both the elements ?

Comment: @ZdaR Yes. Precisely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code may not be optimal but it works just fine.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import scipy.misc as smp
import os


l=[]   
res = np.zeros( (256,256,3), dtype=np.uint8 )
while(m<=256):
    while(n<=256):
        l=image[i:m,j:n][0][0]
        low=np.array([l[0] - thresh, l[1] - thresh, l[2] - thresh])
        high=np.array([l[0] + thresh, l[1] + thresh, l[2] + thresh])
        mask1=cv2.inRange(image,low,high)
        res = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask = mask1)
        block=0
        a=i
        b=j
        c=m
        d=n
        k=[]
        b=b+x
        d=d+x
        while(b<256 and d<256):
            k=res[a:c,b:d][0][0]
            black=[0,0,0]
            while((k!=black).all() and b<256 and d<256):
                block=block+1
                b=b+x
                d=d+x
                k=res[a:c,b:d][0][0]
            image[i:m,j+x:(n+((block)*x))]=l
            break
        j=j+x
        n=n+y

    i=i+x
    m=m+y
    j=0
    n=x
image= cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
img = smp.toimage( image )
data1 = np.asarray( img, dtype="int32" )
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join('G:/AI package/datasets/btob/',filename),data1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used quite a lot of code to get the first step done, However, the same output can be achieved using numpy functions within 2-3 lines of code as:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def get_mean_color(box):
    return int(np.mean(box[:, :, 0])), int(np.mean(box[:, :, 1])), int(np.mean(box[:, :, 2]))


def get_super_square_pixels(img, super_pix_width):
    height, width, ch = img.shape

    if height % super_pix_width != 0:
        raise Exception("height must be multiple of super pixel width")

    if width % super_pix_width != 0:
        raise Exception("width must be multiple of super pixel width")

    output_img = np.zeros(img.shape, np.uint8)
    for i in xrange(height / super_pix_width):
        for j in xrange(width / super_pix_width):
            src_box = img[i * super_pix_width:(i + 1) * super_pix_width, j * super_pix_width:(j + 1) * super_pix_width]
            mean_val = get_mean_color(src_box)

            output_img[i * super_pix_width:(i + 1) * super_pix_width, j * super_pix_width:(j + 1) * super_pix_width] = mean_val

    return output_img

img = cv2.imread("/path/to/your/img.jpg")
out = get_super_square_pixels(img, 16)
```

Comment: thanks..but your code didn't work for me..it just returned the same image given.

Comment: Yes, I was not able to find the solution to second part of your problem, so I made the existing code simpler so that it can be maintained better.